# Is it a mistake to fail to mention future career plans in an application for admission to an MSc in pure mathematics?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, career-path, application, mathematics

I am applying to various universities to study for an msc in maths or pure maths.

After sending of my application I have realized that I have not mentioned anything in the way future career plans.

Was this a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, unless they specifically asked for it.

This is not a doctorate- research is not the only goal of your masters. You are still a student and you will probably have to take courses as well, and you are there for the education. Your time at the institution is limited (one or two years). I doubt that anyone cares or expects you to know "what you want to do when you grow up". This is hardly significant for PhD applicants, let alone for masters.

You do not need to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your masters are a great time to find out for yourself where you want to take your professional future. Be it a PhD and research or the industry.

Some purely research oriented masters may expect that you continue with research, but still it is your carreer and your life. A master that is well balanced between research and the industry will not have such expectations of you.

And as Michael said, the short answer is you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Those in or applying to PhDs should or should have already found out for themselves where they want or would want to take their professional future?